# When building websites, should I aim for absolute cross-browser consistency or let some default user agent style apply?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

What is your preferred approach when creating websites :

- Make effort so pages looks **exactly the same** on every browser ? or
- Let the browser apply its **default stylesheet** on some specific objects like inputs, borders, colors, etc. ?

The first solution is obviously what we would naturally have in a perfect world, but require a lot more work, CSS hacks, browser specific stylesheets and so on.
Is it what webdesigners should tend to do ?

About the second one, I'm thinking about forms, disabled elements, colors sometimes, table's header and footer... It is a lot easier to let the browser handle it and has the advantage of  being consistent *across websites* for the user.
Is it a good practice or I am being lazy ? How to "sell" this solution to a client that don't care about those considerations ?

---

I'm looking for the pro and the cons of each method.
How to choose between one and another ? Where is the limit ? (How about : stick to the W3C standards and let the browser handle the rest ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The art of web design is to work within the constraints of the medium, of which there are many, and still come up with something 100% functional across many different platforms. It is a challenge to make your pages look good and function completely across all browsers at multiple screen sizes, resolutions, cultures, languages, connection speeds, accessibility issues, etc., If you can just accomplish "not broken in IE" that is something.

Of course I want it to look like it did in Fireworks, but that is not a realistic target. Every single machine is different, so every view of your page will be too.

Answer (score 1):

You some CSS framework like Twitter Bootstrap Or Blue print. There are actually Many out there. Then if you are writing custom CSS I would recommend you to use CSS Preprocessors.

- [List of CSS Frameworks](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/08/11/free-css-frameworks/)
- [List Of CSS Preprocessors](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-css-preprocessors-to-speed-up-development-time)
- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Since Twitter Bootstrap and many in the list cover responsive designs too so you dont need to rework for Tablets and other Equipments.I hope this list will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you would want a consistent look across all browsers.  You don't want to have a lazy attitude as you suggested!!  That is a terrible habit for a developer and leads to poor quality products.

Familiarize yourself with the different frameworks out there that address cross browser issues.  Twitter bootstrap and jQuery are a great place to start.  Also get to know the different browsers and understand what they support and what they don't, so that when you are coding you can avoid certain things!

Answer (score 1):

While most web designers desire consistency across browsers, there's nothing inherently "right" about it being so, and in practice it depends on the nature of the web pages you are creating.

In particular, total consistency runs contrary to the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design). There's no golden rule, do what's right for your client in each situation.